# Solving $\int_D x^3+y^2 \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y$ with $D:=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| + |y| \leq 1\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I always had a hard time when it comes to integration task like this one, as I tend to struggle to find the correct limits for the integration:

> Let $D:= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x| + |y| \leq 1\}$. Compute
> \begin{align}
> \int_D x^3+y^2 \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y.
> \end{align}

First, I visualized the set $D$: It's a square with corner points $(-1,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$.
(https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Cx%7C+%2B+%7Cy%7C+%E2%89%A4+1).

Due to the absolute values in the condition $|x| + |y| \leq 1$ I find it hard to get the right limits. Here's what I came up with so far:

I looked at the regions where $y < 0$ and $y > 0$ and wrote the integral as

\begin{align}
\int_D x^3+y^2 \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y = \int_{-1}^0  \int_{-1-y}^{1+y} x^3+y^2\  \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y \ + \int_{0}^1  \int_{y-1}^{1-y} x^3+y^2\  \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y. 
\end{align}

Why? Considering $y < 0$ the two sides of the square in this region can be described as $y = -x+1$ and $y = x-1$. Hence, $x = 1-y$ and $x= 1+y$. Equally, looking at $y > 0$ we find $y = x+1$ and $y = -x+1$ and therefore $x = y-1$ and $x = 1-y$.

Can someone please verify my idea?

Comment: You can ignore $x^3$ as the region is symmetrical and for $y^2$  just use fubini theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your description of the domain $D$ is correct. However you can use symmetry in order to make the evaluation simpler.

Note that the domain is symmetric with respect to the lines $x=0$ and $y=0$. Therefore, since the function $x^3$ is odd and $y^2$ is even, it follows that
$$\iint_D x^3+y^2 \, dxdy=\iint_D x^3 \, dxdy+\iint_D y^2 \, dx dy=0+4\int_{y=0}^1y^2\left(\int_{x=0}^{1-y}\, dx\right) dy$$
which is easy to find.